# How to load a struct knowing the first element?

Tags: c++, c, struct, c99

I see in some places

```
struct dri2_egl_config *dri2_conf = dri2_egl_config(conf);
```

where the struct is

```
struct dri2_egl_config
{
   _EGLConfig         base;
   const __DRIconfig *dri_single_config;
   const __DRIconfig *dri_double_config;
};
```

and `conf` is `_EGLConfig*`.
But when I tried this on C++, it doesn't compile. How can I do this on C++ to access the other struct parameters?

Comment: For C++ it would just be: `dri2_egl_config *dri2_conf = dri2_egl_config(conf);`.

Comment: @PaulR Sir, I had never come across this . Can you please elaborate a bit what is being done here?

Comment: It's a little confusing because `dri2_egl_config` is being used as a function name while `struct dri2_egl_config` is a struct definition. A better fix would be to make the struct definition compatible with C and C++ (e.g. using a typedef).

Comment: @SouravGhosh In C++ a struct is the same thing as a class (just with different default visibility of members). Therefore you can omit the `struct` keyword when defining a variable. (You don't do `struct x *foo;` in C++, just `x *foo;`.)

Comment: @cdhowie ok, that part understood. and what about `dri2_egl_config(conf);` part? Sorry i don't know `c++`, but is any chance that's a constructor?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It seems unlikely that it's a constructor. It seems likely as PaulR says here that `dri2_egl_config()` is also a function, which is going to cause problems in C++. I don't see any other way this would work, since the result is assigned to a pointer.

Comment: The names with a double underscore are reserved in both C and C++; they should not be used in normal code. Are you sure that the library encourages you to use those names?  (If it does, those libraries are out of line.)

Comment: As always, please give us the diagnostic that your compiler produces. Otherwise this can only be guess work. `dri2_egl_config` also could be a macro, whatever...

Comment: It was a strange macro called _EGL_DRIVER_STANDARD_TYPECASTS(dri2_egl) which creates the correct functions and I doesn't put the header in was defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lookslike inheritance in C. For both C++ and C the standard ensures that there is no reordering of fields.
Therefore in C the base fields address is guaranteed to be the same as the whole structs.

dri2_egl_config() in C seems to be a normal Funktion. in C++ it would be a constructor never returning a pointer.
Also the addressing in C++ is more complicated if you habe to consider virtual information. For simple cases whith no virtual methods and so on you can still address via address offsets if you know field sizes. 
But this would require casts to get pointer types consistent. Therefore it seems that dri2_egl_config() returns a dri2_egl_config *. And this is all straight forward C.

Comment: Yes, it was a functions but created with a macro, this is the reason that I couldn't find the function.